# Why isn't InputQuery returning bool?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I've followed the [clear documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Dialogs.InputQuery) to implement an input dialog box.  It works fine.  But, now i want to ignore the user input if they click cancel.  Below is quote from that documentation.

"If the user clicks the **OK** button, **InputQuery** returns `True`; **InputQuery** returns `False` otherwise."

So, i tried the following code and the error i'm getting is `E2034 Cannot convert void to bool` when i run on Win32 and `bccaarm error 1711 value of type void is not contextually convertible to bool` on Android.

```
if (InputQuery(caption, Prompts, sizeof(Prompts)/sizeof(Prompts[0]) - 1, Defaults, sizeof(Defaults)/sizeof(Defaults[0]) - 1, (TInputCloseQueryProc *)Met)){
   // clicked OK
} else {
   // clicked cancel
}
```

How can i test if `OK` or `Cancel` clicked?  Below is the declaration for `InputQuery` and it should be bool.  I'm confused.

```
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE bool __fastcall InputQuery _DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE1("Use FMX.DialogService methods") (const System::UnicodeString ACaption, const System::UnicodeString *APrompts, const int APrompts_High, System::UnicodeString *AValues, const int AValues_High, const _di_TInputCloseQueryFunc ACloseQueryFunc = _di_TInputCloseQueryFunc())/* overload */;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last parameter of `InputQuery()`, you are passing in a [`TInputCloseQueryProc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Dialogs.TInputCloseQueryProc), but the declaration you quoted takes a [`TInputCloseQueryFunc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Dialogs.TInputCloseQueryFunc_Methods) instead.

Per the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Dialogs.InputQuery) you linked to, the overload of `InputQuery()` that takes a [`TInputCloseQueryProc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Dialogs.TInputCloseQueryProc) returns a `void`, not a `bool`, hence the conversion error. The overloads that return a `bool` and accept a close callback take either a [`TInputCloseQueryFunc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Dialogs.TInputCloseQueryFunc_Methods) or [`TInputCloseQueryEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Dialogs.TInputCloseQueryEvent). So you need to update your `Met` variable accordingly.

That being said, the `Fmx::Dialogs::InputQuery()` functions/procedures are deprecated, as is clearly shown in the declaration you quoted. You should be using the `Fmx::DialogService` versions of `InputQuery()`, as the deprecation message says. Use either [`TDialogServiceSync::InputQuery()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.DialogService.Sync.TDialogServiceSync.InputQuery) or [`TDialogServiceAsync::InputQuery()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.DialogService.Async.TDialogServiceAsync.InputQuery) as needed <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: Android does not support modal dialogs, so you can't use the *synchronous* versions of `InputQuery()` on Android.</sup>

---

On a side note, C++Builder has an [`EXISTINGARRAY()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Compatibility_Macros) helper macro in `<sysopen.h>` for passing a *static array* where a Delphi-style *open array* is taken, so you don't have to specify the array bounds manually, eg:

```cpp
InputQuery(..., EXISTINGARRAY(Prompts), EXISTINGARRAY(Defaults), ...)
```